# ADB0000 error: Why doesn't my Xamarin.Android project deploy anymore?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, adb

I used to be able to deploy my Xamarin.Android project to devices but for some reason I can't anymore. I can still successfully deploy UWP and iOS.

I get the error:

```
ADB0000: Could not determine the installation path for package com.my_pro.proj. `adb shell pm path com.my_pro.proj` returned ''.
```

Comment: Try manually deleting the app from the emulator/device, then clean/rebuild/redeploy the project.

Comment: @SushiHangover : Unfortunately, that doesn't help.

Comment: Run `adb shell pm uninstall com.my_pro.proj` then try to deploy again. Sometime App manager on Android doesn't fully uninstall the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `adb shell pm uninstall com.my_pro.proj` via the command prompt is the only thing that works for me whenever I have this error.

My hypothesis is that this error happens when the app gets installed for one user of the device manually but not for all users of it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the problem is that the application is not fully uninstalled and hence the package already exists in your device/emulator,

This, in turn, causes an issue while again installing the application.

**How to fix this?**

In your device/emulator, go to **Settings>Installed Apps>AppName** and delete this application and try deploying again, Also note that sometimes in place of AppName the package name is displayed here so in case you do not find your app, look for the package name.

Revert in case of queries